# Time series ARIMA with exogenous variables

Tags: time-series

Anyone know if the ARIMAProcess or TimeSeriesModelFit will handle exogenous variables? The closest question in Mathematica StackExchange is [ARMAX in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136346/armax-in-mathematica) but no one has responded to this question.  If someone does know, responding with a model with 1 times series and n exogenous variables would be helpful.