# ARMAX with `TimeSeriesModelFit`

Tags: time-series

Is there a way to implement [Friedman's ARMAX](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html) model, where `X` is a predictor matrix. This is basically a linear model with with `ARMA` errors. I can see `TimeSeriesModelFit` has `SARIMA` but nor `SARIMAX`.

Aparently this questions was asked [before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152447/time-series-arima-with-exogenous-variables) without answer.